# Either Remote or Local Sandbox, why not both ?

Tags: actionscript-3

WRT : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e3f.html

Why a flash application can either use Remote  or Local Sandbox . What is the problem if it's using both of them ?
Say a flash application at one time communicating with a local file... and also communicating with some file on the server. Isn't that allowed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not allowed because of security reasons, if it was allowed to communicate with both you can potentially take files from the users machine and send them to a server on the web.